# C++ SDL2 can't load any file

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm using SLD2 in order to make a game, All was working perfectly since now.
I think there is a problem the loading file system.
for example, when i tried to load a bmp :

```
#include <iostream>
# include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);  // Initialize SDL2
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          1000, 500, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_Renderer* render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_Surface* image = SDL_LoadBMP("../background.bmp");
    printf(SDL_GetError());

    return 0;
}
```

the SLD_GetError() function return :
`couldn't load ( some random weird chars)`
and it's the same for SDL mixer

it seems that no file (or any type of file) can be load by any SDL2 features...
Why ?

(the exe is in a subfolder, so the background path is correct)
[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba3QL.png)

Comment: Note that relative paths are relative to the current working directory *not* the path of the executable. You could try to use an absolute path to make sure that working directory is actually set the way you expect it to be. Furthermore, you should check the character encoding of your source files. The weird characters could indicate a problem with your file encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with SDL2. The path you are entering is probably invalid because it says "`couldn't load ( some random weird chars )`", that means SDL couldn't find the file. You are using `../` to indicate that your `background.bmp` file is in the parent directory of the current working directory. If you are using an IDE and then build it, SDL expects the file to be in the parent directory of your project folder. If you then run the executable, it expects the file to be in the parent directory of your executable. So try using an absolute path, for example, `C:\users\path-to-file\background.bmp`. If you use that path system, SDL always search for the `background.bmp` in the given path no matter where your executable is located or where you built the program.

Also be aware of escape sequences. use `\\` for backslash. Or you can just use `/`.

Comment: The path doesn't matter, when i use absolute path, there is the same problem. I was talking about that also song file cannot be load, and the weird chars in the return of sdl_getError()

Comment: Well, I tried your code in my computer with a bmp and it worked fine. Did you install SDL2 correctly? Did you move the dll files to the windows folder or to where your executable is located?

Comment: the exe is in the cmake-build-debug path, and I correctly install SDL (put dll file in sysWOW64), actually, I have this issue since I update widows, so I try to reinstall SDL2, but It didn't solve the problem. (it seems to be an encoding error but I don't know)

Comment: Try using `SDL_Image` library (you may have to download it separately). And try to load a png file with it.

Comment: it seems that the IMG_Load function work better than Load_BMP, I don't know why.., but now it works, Thanks !!!! now I think I should use SDL_Image more often.

Comment: I'm glad to hear, have a good day @idimension.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a folder out of the visual studio project and passing the full path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34394014)